# Is there a way to grab the index of an item in Listview?

Tags: qt, qml

I am using listview in Qt/qml and am trying to display a screen that gives font A to the first text in the list, then font B to the second, then A, then B and so on...

I've been trying to use a conditional in the the font property to the effect of
font:(index % 2) fontA : fontB

I haven't been able to accurately grab the index of each and would appreciate any advice or direction, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get index of the delegate currently displayed - QML ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162940/get-index-of-the-delegate-currently-displayed-qml-listview)

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. I'm trying to use the index inside the component, without the x,y coordinates and without requiring the selection of the item. I appreciate the reference though.

Comment: I think your question would profit from adding the code you have right now. Could you add the relevant snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index property for this. It will be available in your delegate, no matter whether its a Component or a direct child. Check the following snippet:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 5

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: listView.width
            height: listView.height / listView.count

            color: index === 1 ? "red" : "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

`index` will hold the index of your item, starting at 0. So in this example, the second item will be colored red.

The same works for components:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 5

        delegate: comp
        
        Component {
            id: comp
            
            Rectangle {
                width: listView.width
                height: listView.height / listView.count
    
                color: index === 1 ? "red" : "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I went another way with my code but I might change it to use this now. The problem I was running into was that the field I was editing was not a child of where I was delegating. Thanks anyhow man!

Comment: I would suggest you always use ‘model.index’ in stead of just ‘index’. Makes it clearer where the value comes from and can avoid conflicts if you use roles of a real model and not just index.